# Do you know a mental device or trick to learn operator precedence and associativity?

Tags: c++, c

This came up in a conversation with a friend of my nephew who is home from uni.  Personally beside the most frequently used ones I never found it all that important and just use parenthesis.  But I don't have to take his exam.  Anything clever out there?

**Edit** Well, a rare moment of near unanimity on SO!  If only professors listened.

Comment: Use braces where it is not clear. Because even if you have this mental trick thew next person to maintain the code may not.

Comment: Adding parentheses everywhere just because you don't know basic operator precedence is not an excuse.

Comment: Most of the precedence rules I know, I know because I've used them often enough.  For those that I don't, I have a list of them (within a c cheat sheet) taped to the wall next to my desk.

Comment: An exam that requires memorization of all of the precedence rules is a poor exam.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know this probably doesn't help you in the context of your exam, but I'll answer the question for anyone else who might stumble upon this:

Don't try to memorize operator precedence, beyond the "common cases" e.g. arithmetic.  If your statement is unclear, either split it into multiple statements or toss in parenthesis.

Answer (score 6):

Given that there are 16 levels of precedence, I don't think there's an easy trick to memorizing them (no "Roy G Biv" or other mnemonic that I know of).

IMO, the important ones to remember are postfix > unary (i.e., `*p++` == `*(p++)`), unary > arithmetic (`~a+b` == `(~a)+b`), bitwise > logical (`a|b&&c` == `(a|b)&&c)`), and that conditional, assignment, and comma operators make up the bottom 3 in that order (`a=b,c` == `(a=b),c`).

This is why reference manuals were invented.  That doesn't help during an exam, of course.

Answer (score 1):

What I do to remember operator precedence (other than arithmetic, which works the same as arithmetic on paper) is that the unary operator always has precedence. Beyond that, I look it up and use parenthesis, as Steven suggests.